# How to left align left-superscript and left-subscript?

Tags: math-mode

I use `\prescript` to set left-superscript and left-subscript:
[image]

but they're not aligned. How to left align them?

Comment: They *are* aligned – right-aligned. This is a pretty natural choice of alignment for left indices. Of course, it’s up to yourself what you prefer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set them as a regular super-/subscript of a blank element:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  {}^{B_{k + 1}}_{B_k} R = \mathrm{Exp}(- {}^{B_k}\theta)
\]

\end{document}
```